# Detect if a camera angle changed

Tags: python, opencv

I have a fixed camera and I need to check if its position or orientation has been changed. I am trying to use OpenCV (calculating diiferencies between a reference image and a new one) for this, but I am pretty new to OpenCV (and image processing in general) but I am not really sure what specific algorithm would be the best to use for this, or how to interpret the results to find if the camera has been moved/rotated. Any ideas? 
Please help,

Comment: Check if you have some object references, or some object near borders image presented on top, bottom,left,right that you can identify

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it would be to register the two frames to each other using [affine image registration](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d61/group__reg.html) from openCV. From this you can extract the rotation and displacement difference between the two frames. Unfortunately this will only work well for in-plane rotations but I still think it is your best bet.

If you post some sample code and data I would be happy to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Canny](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga04723e007ed888ddf11d9ba04e2232de) or [HoughLinesP](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga8618180a5948286384e3b7ca02f6feeb) to find lines,From this you can get two lines,compare it.Maybe this will be effective in some simple background.if some   object in your picture,try sift or other feature extractor,you can take features to find the relationship from two frames.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).